# Поворот изображения с сохранением пропорций и обрезкой (js, canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть функция поворота изображения в canvas:

```
const rotate = async (base64, angle, color) => {
  const img = new Image()
  img.setAttribute('src', base64)
  await (() => { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { img.onload = function() { resolve() } }) })()
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.width = img.width
  canvas.height = img.height
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
  ctx.fillStyle = color
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
  ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2)
  ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI/180);
  ctx.drawImage(img,-canvas.width/2,-canvas.height/2);
  return canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
}
```

Итогом работы функции является следующее (поворот на 30град):

[image: Оригинал]

[image: Поворот на 30 градусов]

Мне бы хотелось сделать так, чтобы не было видно "желтой" области, т.е. обрезалось с сохранением пропорций. Например вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е., надо как-то высчитывать координаты прямоугольника для обрезки либо масштабировать, отсекая лишнее. Есть идеи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наверное есть какой-нибудь хитрый-производительный способ нахождения длин сторон маленького изображения, лежащего внутри повёрнутого. Ну, или по крайней мере готовая библиотека, которую можно просто взять и использовать.

Хотя, в принципе, можно решить задачу "в лоб".

Общая идея алгоритма

Пусть точка `O` — центр исходного изображения, и имеет координаты `(0, 0)`. Тогда, зная ширину `width` и высоту `height` исходного изображения, можно найти координаты вершин исходного изображения. Обозначим точки:

`A` — левый верхний угол.
`B` — правый верхний угол.
`D` — левый нижний угол.

Зная координаты вершин изображения до поворота и угол поворота, можно найти координаты вершин повёрнутого изображения. Обозначим:

`As` — точка `A` после поворота.
`Bs` — точка `B` после поворота.
`Ds` — точка `D` после поворота.

Пусть `AO` — прямая, проходящая через точки `A` и `O`. Назовём её «главной диагональю».
Пусть `BO` — прямая, проходящая через точки `B` и `O`. Назовём её «побочной диагональю».

Найдём точки пересечения главной диагонали и всех сторон повёрнутого изображения.
Найдём расстояния от точки `O` до точек пересечения главной диагонали и сторон повёрнутого изображения.
Среди всех расстояний выберем минимальное.
Если от точки `O` на главной диагонали в обоих направлениях отложить две точки на только что найденном минимальном расстоянии, то получившийся отрезок будет целиком лежать внутри повёрнутого изображения.

(Также заметим, что за счёт симметрии расстояние от точки `O` до точки пересечения главной диагонали и одной из двух параллельных сторон изображения равно расстоянию от `O` до точки пересечения главной диагонали и другой стороны из двух параллельных сторон повёрнутого изображения. Т.е. при поиске расстояний достаточно найти расстояния всего до двух из четырёх точек пересечения.)

Проделаем аналогичные вычисления с побочной диагональю, и получим отрезок на побочной диагонали, целиком лежащий внутри повёрнутого изображения.

Из двух отрезков, лежащих на диагоналях, выберем тот, который короче. Он и будет диагональю маленького изображения.

Диагональ маленького изображения известна. Отношение ширины к высоте у маленького изображения равны таковым у исходного. По теореме Пифагора можно найти ширину/высоту маленького изображения.

Собственно код:

```js
/*
    orig_size = {
        width:  ширина_исходного_изображения,
        height: высота_исходного_изображения
    };
    angle - угол поворота по часовой стрелке в радианах.
*/

function get_small_image_size(orig_size, angle)
{
    function det4(v1, v2, v3, v4)
    {
        return v1 * v4 - v2 * v3;
    }
    function get_intersection_point(line1, line2)
    {
        let {x1, y1, x2, y2} = line1;
        let {x1: x3, y1: y3, x2: x4, y2: y4} = line2;
        
        let x12 = x1 - x2;
        let x34 = x3 - x4;
        let y12 = y1 - y2;
        let y34 = y3 - y4;
        
        let xy12 = det4(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        let xy34 = det4(x3, y3, x4, y4);
        
        let denom = det4(x12, y12, x34, y34);
        
        let x = det4(xy12, x12, xy34, x34) / denom;
        let y = det4(xy12, y12, xy34, y34) / denom;
        
        x = isNaN(x) ? Infinity : x;
        y = isNaN(y) ? Infinity : y;
        return {x, y};
    }
    function rot(point, angle)
    {
        let sin_theta = Math.sin(angle);
        let cos_theta = Math.cos(angle);
        
        let x =  cos_theta * point.x + sin_theta * point.y;
        let y = -sin_theta * point.x + cos_theta * point.y;
        return {x, y};
    }
    function points_to_line(p1, p2)
    {
        return {x1: p1.x, y1: p1.y, x2: p2.x, y2: p2.y};
    }
    function dist2(p1, p2)
    {
        let x = p1.x - p2.x;
        let y = p1.y - p2.y;
        return x * x + y * y;
    }
    
    let {width, height} = orig_size;
    
    let O = {x:  0,           y:  0           };
    let A = {x: -0.5 * width, y:  0.5 * height};
    let B = {x:  0.5 * width, y:  0.5 * height};
    let D = {x: -0.5 * width, y: -0.5 * height};
    
    let As = rot(A, angle);
    let Bs = rot(B, angle);
    let Ds = rot(D, angle);
    
    let AO   = points_to_line(A,  O);
    let BO   = points_to_line(B,  O);
    let AsBs = points_to_line(As, Bs);
    let AsDs = points_to_line(As, Ds);
    
    let AO_AsBs = get_intersection_point(AO, AsBs);
    let AO_AsDs = get_intersection_point(AO, AsDs);
    let BO_AsBs = get_intersection_point(BO, AsBs);
    let BO_AsDs = get_intersection_point(BO, AsDs);
    
    let len_diag1 = Math.min( dist2(AO_AsBs, O), dist2(AO_AsDs, O) );
    let len_diag2 = Math.min( dist2(BO_AsBs, O), dist2(BO_AsDs, O) );
    let len_diag = 2 * Math.sqrt( Math.min(len_diag1, len_diag2) );
    
    let ratio = height / width;
    
    let res = {};
    res.width = len_diag / Math.sqrt(ratio * ratio + 1);
    res.height = ratio * res.width;
    return res;
}

async function rotate(addr)
{
    let img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute('src', addr);
    await (() => { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { img.onload = function() { resolve() } }) })();
    
    let ctx = document.getElementById("canvas_id").getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.width  = img.width;
    ctx.canvas.height = img.height;
    
    let input = document.getElementById("input_id");
    let label = document.getElementById("label_id");
    
    let small_ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
    
    function handler()
    {
        let angle_rad = input.value * Math.PI / 180;
        label.textContent = input.value;
        
        ctx.save();
        {
            ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
            ctx.translate(ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2);
            ctx.rotate(angle_rad);
            ctx.drawImage(img, -ctx.canvas.width / 2, -ctx.canvas.height / 2);
        }
        ctx.restore();
        
        ctx.save()
        {
            let orig_size = {width: img.width, height: img.height};
            let {width: small_width, height: small_height} = get_small_image_size(orig_size, angle_rad);

            let small_x = Math.round(ctx.canvas.width / 2 - small_width / 2);
            let small_y = Math.round(ctx.canvas.height / 2 - small_height / 2);

            small_width  = Math.round(small_width);
            small_height = Math.round(small_height);

            small_ctx.canvas.width  = small_width;
            small_ctx.canvas.height = small_height;
            small_ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, small_x, small_y, small_width, small_height, 0, 0, small_width, small_height);
            
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(small_ctx.canvas, small_x, small_y);
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }
    
    handler();
    input.addEventListener("input", () => label.textContent = input.value);
    input.addEventListener("change", handler);
}

rotate("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezAfF.jpg");
```

```html
<p>
    <input id = "input_id" type = "range" min = "-180" max = "180" value = "30">
    <label id = "label_id" for = "input_id"></label>
</p>
<p><canvas id = "canvas_id"></canvas></p>
```

Comment: Я думаю, стоит заменить событие `change` на событие `input`.

Comment: @Voprositel, оно слишком часто происходит. Если активно дёргать ползунок из стороны в сторону, то начинает подтормаживать.

Comment: Странно, у меня даже на старом ноутбуке не подтормаживает, возможно дело в браузере

Comment: Ничего не понял, но код работает. Спасибо!